# Is fast implementation of pow(x, 0.5f) faster than fast sqrt(x)?

Tags: c++, c, performance, math

I'm wondering if fast implementation of pow(), for example [this one](http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/10/04/optimized-pow-approximation-for-java-and-c-c/), is a faster way to get square root of an integer than fast sqrt(x). We know that

```
sqrt(x) = pow(x, 0.5f)
```

I cannot test speed myself because I did not find fast implementation of sqrt.
My question is: Is fast implementation of pow(x, 0.5f) faster than fast sqrt(x) ?

Edit: I meant powf - pow that takes floats intead of doubles. (doubles are more misleading)

Comment: That implementation is an approximation, which means it will have much higher error than using sqrt, which is why it can be faster.

Comment: Changing to single-precision parameters and return types changes the numbers in my answer below: pow approximation takes 9 cycles instead of 6 (it is written to operate on double, so the types have to be converted; possibly it could be rewritten for float), powf takes 16 cycles instead of 29, sqrt approximation takes 7 instead of 10 (inverse effect, it is written for float, so the type conversions go away), and sqrtf takes 16 instead of 29.

Comment: The number `0.5` can be represented exactly in IEEE floating point, so the compiler is allowed to rewrite `pow(x, 0.5)` as `sqrt(x)` for you, and the C library is allowed to do `return sqrt(x)` from inside `pow` when the second argument is 0.5.  I don't know of any implementation that does either of these things, but I would not be surprised to learn of one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With regard to C standard library `sqrt` and `pow`, the answer is **no**.

First, if `pow(x, .5f)` were faster than an implementation of `sqrt(x)`, the engineer assigned to maintain sqrt would replace the implementation with `pow(x, .5f)`.

Second, implementations of sqrt in commercial libraries are typically optimized specifically to perform that task, often by people who are knowledgeable about writing high-performance software and who write in or near assembly language to get the best performance available from the processor.

Third, many processors have instructions to perform sqrt or to assist in calculating it. (Commonly, there is an instruction to provide an estimate of the reciprocal of the square root and an instruction to refine that estimate.)

#### However

The code you linked/question you asked is about attempting a crude approximation of `sqrt` using a crudely approximated `pow`.

I converted the final version of the pow approximation routine referred to in the question to C and measured the run time of it when computing `pow(3, .5)`. I also measured the run-time of the system (Mac OS X 10.8) pow and sqrt and of [the sqrt approximation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) (with one iteration and multiplying by the argument at the end to get the square root, rather than its inverse).

First, the computed results: The pow approximation returns 1.72101. The sqrt approximation returns 1.73054. The correct value, returned by the system pow and sqrt, is 1.73205.

Running in 64-bit mode on a MacPro4,1, the pow approximation takes about 6 cycles, the system pow takes 29 cycles, the square root approximation takes 10 cycles, and the system sqrt takes 29 cycles. These times may include some overhead for loading arguments and storing results (I used volatile variables to force the compiler not to optimize away otherwise useless loop iterations, so that I could measure them).

(These times are “effective throughput”, in effect the number of CPU cycles from when one call begins to when another can begin.)

Comment: I wrote the above to compare sqrt to pow in a typical library. However, the question asks us to compare sqrt to the pow approximation. In this case, the (very bad) pow approximation might beat sqrt on some platforms. However, note that the pow approximation claims typical errors of 5% to 12%. The error in a typical sqrt implementation is usually around .000000000000222%. So it is not a fair comparison.

Comment: Indeed.  I took that into account in my answer, but I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: ... and if one *is* willing to compromise accuracy, a direct approximation of `sqrt( )` would be faster still.

Comment: Approximating `sqrt` with error that bad is trivial. Just operate on the bits of the floating point representation, halving the exponent, and then doing a cheap fix-up on the mantissa....

Answer (score 2):

Results running the following code under MSVC++ 2013 64-bit mode, full optimization. ~9X performance for sqrt();

Distance is 2619435809228.278300

Pow() elapsed time was 18413.000000 milliseconds

Distance is 2619435809228.278300

Sqrt() elapsed time was 2002.000000 milliseconds

```
#define LOOP_KNT 249000000  // (SHRT_MAX * 1024)

int main(void)    {
    time_t start = clock();

    double distance = 0, result = 0;
    start = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<LOOP_KNT; i++) {
        result = pow(i, 0.50);
        distance += result;
    }
    printf("\nDistance is %f", distance);
   printf("\nPow() elapsed time was %f milliseconds", (double)clock() - (double)(start));

   distance = 0, result = 0;
   start = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<LOOP_KNT; i++) {
        result = sqrt(i);
        distance += result;
    }
    printf("\nDistance is %f", distance);
    printf("\nSqrt() elapsed time was %f milliseconds", (double)clock() - (double)(start));

   printf("\nHit any key to end program.\n");
   getchar();

   return 0;
}
```

No hand-wringing, theorizing, or pontification required. Just write the benchmark and observe the result.

Comment: Thanks for answer; however `sqrt` and `pow` from standard lib are both very slow.

Comment: Note: Tried the same on my Cygwin 64-bit PC - ratio 1.04.  `pow() vs sqrt()`.

Comment: @Zaffy, Close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades. A 25% error makes your linked method worthless. It's also in Java, so crippled for performance right out of the gate. 

"This is really very compact. The calculation only requires 2 shifts, 1 mul, 2 add, and 2 register operations. That’s it! In my tests it usually within an error margin of 5% to 12%, in extreme cases sometimes up to 25%. "

Answer (score 1):

In general, given the same constraints on error, a more specific problem can be more optimized than a more general one.

Therefore, you could take that algorithm, and replace b with the constant 0.5, and now you have a sqrt() that is at least as fast as that pow().  Now that it's constant, the compiler (or a human) can make optimizations based on that.

Please note that that pow() function is an approximation and has (relatively) large error, and therefore is not nearly as accurate as say, most library sqrt functions.  If you relax your implementation of sqrt to the same limits of approximation, you could indeed make it at least as fast.

Comment: sqrt is an algebraic function, while pow() is a transcendental function, but In practice they are both approximations, usually Newton-Raphson successive approximations. http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der07/der07.html

Comment: Good `sqrt()` implementations can be provable accurate to within 0.5 ULP.  `pow()` rarely have that provable accuracy.  Good implementations will _typically_ return a result within 1  ULP.